# verification error inside children in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a self within my children, but this is giving me an error if I make mistakes within agitated children.
What am I doing wrong?

What I'm wanting to do is:

```
if(snapshot.data.Facebook != null){
   // display the image if different from null
   Image.asset("assets/images/facebook.png",height: 40,), SizedBox(width: 10),
 }
```

My code: ----------------------------------------------------------

```
Padding(
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
     child: Row(
     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
     children: [

     if(snapshot.data.Facebook != null){

     };


                              Image.asset("assets/images/facebook.png",height: 40,), SizedBox(width: 10),

                              Image.asset("assets/images/instagram.png", height: 40,), SizedBox(width: 10),

                              Image.asset("assets/images/linkdin.png", height: 40,), SizedBox(width: 10),

                              Image.asset("assets/images/pinterest.png", height: 40,), SizedBox(width: 10),

                              Image.asset("assets/images/skype.png", height: 40,), SizedBox(width: 10),

                              Image.asset("assets/images/twitter.png", height: 40,), SizedBox(width: 10),

                              Image.asset("assets/images/whatsapp.png", height: 40,), SizedBox(width: 10),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
```

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the red line in if statement on your picture? Are you trying to display different images in your row when snapshot != null?

Comment: That's right, disregard the images below the if.
I'm actually trying to make a check if my object is different from null it displays the image within the condition.

As it started to give the error I did not put the image field inside it.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like

if(snapshot.data.Facebook != null){

            // displays the image if different from null
            Image.asset("assets/images/facebook.png",height: 40,), SizedBox(width: 10),

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version of if/else inside widget. If the condition is true, widget in front of `?` will be showed and `:` for false condition.

```
Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
            child: snapshot.data.Facebook != null //check the condition
                //return Row with images in it if snapshot.data.Facebook != null is true
                ? Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/facebook.png",
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/instagram.png",
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/linkdin.png",
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/pinterest.png",
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/skype.png",
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/twitter.png",
                        height: 40,),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/whatsapp.png",
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                    ],
                  )
                //return empty Row if snapshot.data.Facebook != null is false
                : Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                       //you can add more widget in here
                    ],
                  )
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a function which returns list of Widgets and add that function  into your rows. Something like

UPDATE:

```
  List<Widget> populateRow() {
    if(snapshot.data.Facebook != null){
      return [Image.asset("assets/images/facebook.png",height: 40,)], 
    } else if (snapshot.data.Instagram != null){
      return [Image.asset("assets/images/instagram.png",height: 40,)],
    } ...

    return [];
  }
```

and in your row add the function like this

```
children: populateRow()
```

Please check if it works. I haven't test it. And obviously you can modify the function to display whatever images you want

Comment: hello I put the code, but it is giving error in the application confirm below

children != null: is not true

Comment: List<Image> populateRow(){
                if(snapshot.data.Facebook != null){
                  Image.asset("assets/images/facebook.png",height: 40,);
                }else if(snapshot.data.Instagram != null){
                  Image.asset("assets/images/instagram.png",height: 40,);
                }
              }

Comment: my idea if nothing has been filled in falls for another check

Comment: you forgot to add return statement in your method and method must return Widget.. Please see updated answer